# Concatenate items in two nested lists to pairs in tuples

Tags: python, list, zip, nested, tuples

I have two nested lists:

```
ls1 = [["a","b"], ["c","d"]]
ls2 = [["e","f"], ["g","h"]]
```

and I'd like the following result [(a,e), (b,f), (c,g), (d,h)]

I've tried zip(a,b), how do I zip nested lists into a list with tupled pairs?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [itertools.chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and `zip`:

```
>>> ls1 = [["a","b"], ["c","d"]]
>>> ls2 = [["e","f"], ["g","h"]]
>>> 
>>> zip(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ls1), itertools.chain.from_iterable(ls2))
[('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'g'), ('d', 'h')]
```

Comment: Good, but readability would be improved by using `itertools.chain` over `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.  (And yes, I know the `from_iterable` version is faster.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, or `cfi = itertools.chain.from_iterable` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` twice inside a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> ls1 = [["a","b"], ["c","d"]]
>>> ls2 = [["e","f"], ["g","h"]]
>>> [y for x in zip(ls1, ls2) for y in zip(*x)]
[('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'g'), ('d', 'h')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to flatten your lists, and could use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce # in Python 3.x
from operator import add
zip(reduce(add, ls1), reduce(add, ls2))
```

Comment: Note that if your lists are very long this will bog down quickly from the repeated creation of new lists for each addition.

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic method is to use the star notation and `itertools.chain` to flatten the lists before zipping them. The star notation unpacks an iterable into arguments to a function, while the `itertools.chain` function chains the iterables in its arguments together into a single iterable.

```
    ls1 = [["a","b"], ["c","d"]]
    ls2 = [["e","f"], ["g","h"]]

    import itertools as it
    zip(it.chain(*ls1), it.chain(*ls2))
```