# How to merge two nested lists and output a list of lists of tuples?

Tags: python, list, nested, zip, tuples

I have two nested lists, `list_a` and `list_b`:

```
list_a=[['a','b'],['c','d','e'],['f','g','f']]
list_b=[[5,7],[2,3,2],[4,7,8]]
```

I am trying to produce `list_c` which would be the result of merging each element in `list_a` with its corresponding element in `list_b` e.g `list_a[1][1]` with `list_b[1][1]` and `list_a[1][2]` with `list_b[1][2]`, etc. to produce a list of lists of tuples.

```
list_c=[[('a',5),('b',7)],[('c',2),('d',3),('e',2)],[('f',4),('g',7),('f',8)]]
```

I had already tried:

```
list_c=[]
for list1 in list_a:
    for list2 in list_b:
        list_c.append(list(zip(list1,list2)))
```

But the output for this is a list of lists of tuples of all possible combinations of the elements in the original lists:

```
[[('a', 5), ('b', 7)], [('a', 2), ('b', 3)], 
 [('a', 4), ('b', 7)], [('c', 5), ('d', 7)],...
 [('f', 2), ('g', 3), ('f', 2)], 
 [('f', 4), ('g', 7), ('f', 8)]]
```

I feel like I'm close to the right answer, but am missing something simple. How do I produce a `list_c` of the structure I am looking for? (Preserving the order matters, since I'd like to use this for working on a CSV file)

This is an extension to the question asked here:
[Concatenate items in two nested lists to pairs in tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845767/concatenate-items-in-two-nested-lists-to-pairs-in-tuples/20846166)

But I've been unable to find any similar questions that don't involve flattening the resulting list into something like:

```
list_c=[('a',5),('b',7),('c',2),('d',3),('e',2),('f',4),('g',7),('f',8)]
```

Comment: You could use the 'flattening method' from the topic: [ Concatenate items in two nested lists to pairs in tuples] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845767/concatenate-items-in-two-nested-lists-to-pairs-in-tuples/20846166) to have a first list like that:`[('a',5),('b',7),('c',2),('d',3),('e',2),('f',4),('g',7),('f',8)]`, then create an empty list, and apppend the previous one into it, no ?

Comment: [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `zip` over `list_a` and `list_b`, not do a nested for-loop (a product):
something to the effect of:

```
[list(zip(a,b)) for a,b in zip(list_a, list_b)]
```

In other words:

```
result = []
for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    result.append(list(zip(a,b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension

```
a=[['a','b'],['c','d','e'],['f','g','f']]
b=[[5,7],[2,3,2],[4,7,8]]

c = [list(zip(i,j)) for i,j in zip(a,b)]

print(c)

"""
output 


[[('a', 5), ('b', 7)],
 [('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 2)],
 [('f', 4), ('g', 7), ('f', 8)]]

"""
```

using lambda function this can be done as

```
d=list(map(lambda x,y:list(zip(x,y)),a,b))
print(d) 
"""
output 

[[('a', 5), ('b', 7)],
 [('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 2)],
 [('f', 4), ('g', 7), ('f', 8)]]

"""
```

Comment: Don't use `reduce(add` to flatten a list, it is an anti-pattern because it is quadratic time. This is also not the desired output.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i just suggest a method, you are right it takes time, and output is correct. i am not considering fast solution here

Comment: Output is *not* correct. The desired output is `list_c=[[('a',5),('b',7)],[('c',2),('d',3),('e',2)],[('f',4),('g',7),('f',8)]]`. And don't suggest well-known anti-patterns, unless you want to be downvoted. Thousands of people will copy-and-paste this without a thought. There is enough lazy programmers out there writing crappy software. Don't enable that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga those lazy programmers don't even read the question completely. you  need to read again what the op has asked in output

Comment: No, *you* need to read it again. The OP *explicitly stated* that they want to *avoid flattening the list*. They even linked to a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845767/concatenate-items-in-two-nested-lists-to-pairs-in-tuples/20846166) with your solution. You have merely provided an inefficient, over-engineered (`reduce(add, ...)` -> `sum(...)`) alternative way of accomplishing that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillagaI am sorry for being rude and proving wrong ( too much-engineered solution). I have updated the solution. thanks for your help to improve the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_c = []
for i, element_a in enumerate(list_a):
    element_b = list_b[i]
    merged_list = []
    for j in range(len(element_a)):
        merged_list.append((element_a[j], element_b[j]))
    list_c.append(merged_list)
```

Create new tuple for each element in each list index and append to master list

Answer (score 0):

Since the best and shorter method is already taken.., another option with the good old verbose for loop:

```
list_c = []
for i, a in enumerate(list_a):
  tmp = []
  for j, b in enumerate(list_b[i]):
    tmp.append((a[j], b))
  list_c.append(tmp)

list_c
#=> [[('a', 5), ('b', 7)], [('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 2)], [('f', 4), ('g', 7), ('f', 8)]]
```